# How to prepare new 'main store listing' beforehand at Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I would like to publish updated application to `google play console`
And I have created `alpha track`.
But I want to change `store listing`. I mean, `screenshots`
I know where to change them.

[image]

But as I understood, this will start applying of new screenshots after my submission,
but I what to have this listing updated tougether with sending of build from 'alpha' to 'production'

Please, tell me if you know how to publish these changes exactly together.
And avoid case when listing with new screenshots updated earlier, but application after this.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to publish changes together, then you can use managed publishing.

You can find this setting in "Publishing Overview" > Click "Manage" on "Managed publishing status" > then you can enable managed publishing.

After you enable this, you can modify the store listing as well as releases, and have them reviewed by Google Play, without having them publish automatically to Google Play Store. Then after all the changes have been reviewed, you can publish them to Google Play at exactly the same time.

More information here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859654?hl=en-GB